# Ion_auth - multiple users on one session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, ion-auth

I've been using ion_auth with codeigniter for a system for 3 years now. Suddenly the sessions are not working as they should.

When user A logs into the website, their session seems to be shared with all the other users. So when user B then navigates to any of the routes, they are "logged in" with user A's credentials.

I've tested this with multiple users, as soon as a user logs into the site, all the other users that visit the site are automatically logged in with that user's credentials / session.

If the user logs out and the auth/logout route is called, the session is not destroyed and all users stay logged in on that session.

The initial redirect after login goes to /vehicle/index . Once you navigate to any other page that checks if the user is logged in, you are redirected to login.

Main Controller code:

```
public function vehicle()
{

    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('auth/login');
    }
    else {
        if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) {

            /**
            *
            * User IS NOT admin
            *
            **/
            // Get User_id if standard user
            $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
            // Build Crud
```

Controller auth.php

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->data['title'] = "Logout";

    // log the user out
    $logout = $this->ion_auth->logout();

    // redirect them to the login page
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
    redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
}
```

Server PHP Version 5.6.30 - Build Date Feb 3 2017 07:51:58

Codeigniter version 2.2.1 - version not changed

Ion_Auth Config:

```
$config['hash_method']    = 'bcrypt';   // sha1 or bcrypt, bcrypt is 

STRONGLY recommended
$config['default_rounds'] = 8;      // This does not apply if random_rounds is set to true
$config['random_rounds']  = FALSE;
$config['min_rounds']     = 5;
$config['max_rounds']     = 9;
$config['salt_prefix']    = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<') ? '$2a$' : '$2y$';

/*
 | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Authentication options.
 | -------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | maximum_login_attempts: This maximum is not enforced by the library, but is
 | used by $this->ion_auth->is_max_login_attempts_exceeded().
 | The controller should check this function and act
 | appropriately. If this variable set to 0, there is no maximum.
 */
$config['site_title']                 = "Cars in the park";       // Site Title, example.com
$config['admin_email']                = "nice@verynice.co.za"; // Admin Email, admin@example.com
$config['default_group']              = 'members';           // Default group, use name
$config['admin_group']                = 'admin';             // Default administrators group, use name
$config['identity']                   = 'email';             // A database column which is used to login with
$config['min_password_length']        = 8;                   // Minimum Required Length of Password
$config['max_password_length']        = 20;                  // Maximum Allowed Length of Password
$config['email_activation']           = TRUE;               // Email Activation for registration
$config['manual_activation']          = TRUE;               // Manual Activation for registration
$config['remember_users']             = FALSE;                // Allow users to be remembered and enable auto-login
$config['user_expire']                = 30;               // How long to remember the user (seconds). Set to zero for no expiration
$config['user_extend_on_login']       = FALSE;               // Extend the users cookies every time they auto-login
$config['track_login_attempts']       = TRUE;               // Track the number of failed login attempts for each user or ip.
$config['track_login_ip_address']     = TRUE;                // Track login attempts by IP Address, if FALSE will track based on identity. (Default: TRUE)
$config['maximum_login_attempts']     = 3;                   // The maximum number of failed login attempts.
$config['lockout_time']               = 600;                 // The number of seconds to lockout an account due to exceeded attempts
$config['forgot_password_expiration'] = 0;                   // The number of milliseconds after which a forgot password request will expire. If set to 0, forgot password requests will not expire.
```

Session config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 30;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 30;
```

Session variable(for logged in user. All other users have the same info in the session):

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1148 [ip_address] => [username] => testing [password] => $2y$08$Q4fjUfsuOKM/Q8cnQt6j0uSXP.3mCqMnzDY1nBA9RDlwm [salt] => sadsda [email] => email@email.com [activation_code] => [forgotten_password_code] => [forgotten_password_time] => [remember_code] => [created_on] => 1426181328 [last_login] => 1490008619 [active] => 1 [first_name] => Name [last_name] => Testing [company] => [phone] => [user_id] => 1148 )
```

Comment: did you perform a CI upgrade, was there an upgrade of php at your server? please check all possible configuration changes and edit it to your question. thanks

Comment: If it used to work, and you didn't edit the code, then what you describe is impossible... although two users sharing the same session is already fairly unlikely with a properly installed Ion Auth.   Check the file modification dates to verify that nobody else has tampered with anything.  Also, I'm very suspicious about how you're testing this... are you using different machines and/or browsers to verify these observations?

Comment: I'm testing this on different devices, different connections and the result stays the same. A session is created and everyone stays on that one session until it expires. Logout doesn't destroy the session, but the logged_in() returns false, so all pages redirect back to login after the first redirect.

Comment: Do the problem persist even if you use database storage for the sessions? Set `sess_use_database = TRUE` and create the table ci_sessions accordingly to help narrow the bug search

Comment: I would agree with @MichaelK. Try changing session mode from file to DB and create ci_sessions table and then test.

Comment: Changed to DB sessions. The session is created in the database, but the user is immediately redirected back to login. When logging in again, another session is created. Manually going to the logout route, clears the user data in the session, but the session is not deleted and a new session is created. Logging in again, adds user data to the newly created session and redirects back to login.

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting? Also, did you do any change in session management code?

Comment: Did you check the value of the Cookie request-header of the clients? Do they have the same session id or is it different for each client? And do you use a proxy or loadbalancer between the server/client connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Change the following settings in config:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

## Create Table `ci_sessions`:

For MySQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ci_sessions`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

For PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "ci_sessions" (
    "id" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "ip_address" varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" bigint DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    "data" text DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX "ci_sessions_timestamp" ON "ci_sessions" ("timestamp");
```

## To Use Database as Your Session Driver

The ‘database’ driver uses a relational database such as MySQL or PostgreSQL to store sessions. This is a popular choice among many users, because it allows the developer easy access to the session data within an application - it is just another table in your database.

However, there are some conditions that must be met:

- Only your **default database connection** (or the one that you access as `$this->db` from your controllers) can be used.
- You must have the **Query Builder enabled**.
- You can **NOT** use a **persistent connection**.
- You can **NOT** use a connection with the **cache_on setting enabled**.

Source: [Codeigniter Session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#id19)

Answer (score 0):

This was a server problem(shared hosting). I moved the complete app over to a new host(vps hosting) and everything worked as it did before.

Changing to DB sessions as Rafiq and the other commentators suggested did help with testing.